# Linux untar command shows file names as question marks

Tags: linux, tar

A while ago I had compressed an application using Linux "tar -cf" command. At that time some of the file names were in a different language.

Now when I uncompress using "tar -xf" it shows the file names in the other language as question marks.

Is there a way that when I uncompress it keeps the original file names as they were?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Good question ! It's expected that like any Unix command, tar could pipe its output to another program, if possible including filename data. A quick googling reveals that this is the case: as described in this blog post, GNU tar supports the --to-command parameter to write the output to a pipe, instead of directly operating on the directory.

http://osmanov-dev-notes.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/how-to-handle-filename-encodings-in.html

So it's a matter of writing a script to convert the filename to UTF-8, like it's done in the cited post. Another option, also described in the text, that becomes obvious after you read it is to simply extract everything and then write a script to convert every file in the directory. There's a trivial php script in the link that does this.

Finally, you can always write your own custom tar version with the help of scripting languages, and that's easy. Python, for example has the tarfile module built in the standard library:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#examples

You could use TarFile.extractfile(), shutils.copyfileobj() and str.decode() in a loop to manually extract the files while changing the file name encoding.

References:

http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC84

http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/iconv/

Comment: Thanks hdante. That didn't help one reason is I am not a Python programmer. Also the app itself is very big and files are spread across hundreds of directories.

Comment: copy-paste dispatch_arc_file.sh described in Osmanov's page. It's a shell script, not python code. Then run the comand as he wrote in the description with the old encoding as a parameter.